# CSS and JS, make div follows scroll

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

I have tried using position fixed but I just cannot seem to find out how to do it, I want my sidebar to stay fixed along the screen as the user scrolls, my sidebar element id is `#displayside` can someone please help me out and explain what I must do to have this fixed.

Please excuse me if this question is too obvious but I am just starting to code and I need help.

Thanks!

```
#displayside {
     width: 15%;
    /* margin-left: 25px; */
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    margin:3px;
    background-image:url('/resources/images/htmlbg.jpeg');
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
   -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
   position: fixed;
```

Comment: Giving it position fixed will indeed achieve what you want. If it's not working, post some code or, better, set up a JS Fiddle, otherwise we're working completely blindly.

Comment: thanks, i'll do a second look and if it still doesnt work i'll post the css.

Comment: Just to expand, how would I make only 1 element go with scroll? So I have the main content scrolling with fixed headers and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position:fixed`

```
#displayside
{
 position:fixed;
}
```

and set top and left according to your requirement

as

```
#displayside
    {
     position:fixed;
     left:10px;
     top:10px;
    }
```

Comment: `#displayside {
width: 15%;
/*margin-left: 25px;*/
float:right;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
margin:3px;
background-image:url('/resources/images/htmlbg.jpeg');
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
position: fixed;`?? its not working!

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the positioning on-screen, it works now.