# interface following the screen instead of the background

Tags: css

If you look at twitter.com, the interface (sign up boxes, login boxes) follows the screen with the background being scrolled.

I have tried to search all over the internet (and trying to find the exact query for it) but i could not find the answer.

Has someone out there, done it?

Comment: The magic words are [_css fixed positioning_](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+fixed+positioning).

Comment: Or `position:fixed`. But that is just 'normal' CSS and not CSS3 / HTML5 or jQuery.

Comment: thanks. i'll change it. just curious, why didn't anyone answer in the box so i can just put a nice tick on it?

Comment: I was looking for a good existing question to close this as a duplicate of, but it seems suprisingly hard to find any even though this _must_ have been asked before. Here's one, though: [CSS and JS, make div follows scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395201/css-and-js-make-div-follows-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position: fixed

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jplahn/MBD6C/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="banner">This is the banner</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 #banner {
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
 }

.content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
```